AWS Elastic Beanstalk application load balancer 504 gateway time-out
I have created a elastic beanstalk docker environment. The sample application runs totally fine, I was able to access the application with the domain http://xxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/. This ensures that the beanstalk environment is configured correctly. This environment was created without nginx.
I updated the environment with my custom Directus application which is using the port 8055.
I am able to access the application with the EC2 public DNS ec2-x-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8055. I did this just to make sure that the application is accessible on port 8055
I updated my target group associated with the application load balancer. Made sure the port 8055 is the target port. Also, the security groups associated with the EC2 instances have been updated to accept HTTP traffic on port 8055 from the security group of the load balancer.
Also, the health check requests are facing Request time out error. The health check endpoint is /server/ping which response back with pong.
Despite my best efforts I still get the 504 gateway time-out error when accessing the application with the domain http://xxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/.
I am guessing this has something to do with the load balancer?
Any help/ideas to fix this issues will be appreciated.
